# how to add image between two divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to add image between two divs like this "movie me" [in this link](http://webredox.net/demo/wp/movieme/demo/) in my code [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjwGLX)?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color: red;height: 100%">
        <hello>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color: blue;height: 100%">
        <hello>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flexbox (not sure if this breaks bootstrap behavior but i think it doesn't):

HTML:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color: red;height: 100%">
    <hello>
  </div>

  <!--Example div could be an image-->
  <div class="image"></div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color: blue;height: 100%">
    <hello>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.row-fluid { 
  height: 100%; 
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
  justify-content :center;
}

.image {
  /*Relevant part for image div*/
  position : absolute;
  z-index: 100;

  /*Less relevant part for image div*/
  width : 50px; 
  height : 50px; 
  background-color:green; 
}
```

[code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdVRWV)

Comment: thanks works like charm but when i add image the responsive takes a hit [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kmzaqp) can u help with the issue

Comment: You need to remove the div (was just an example) and apply the styles to your image only. see here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjwRXN (added border radius to make it round, just remove if you dont need it). Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem, i need to score ;-)